# How to print method name in the log file using log4cplus

Tags: c++, logging, log4cplus

I have written a wrapper library on log4cplus. My library has `LogMessage` function inside which i am calling log4cplus library function to store the log message.

eg.
application.cpp

```
int main()
{
LogMessage(DEBUG_LEVEL, __FILE__, __LINE__, "This is main function");
return 0;
}
```

mylibrary.cpp

```
HRESULT
LogMessage(
__in    DWORD dwLogLevel,
__in    LPSTR lpszFileName,
__in    DWORD dwLineNumber,
__in    LPSTR lpszLogMessage
)
{
        //
        // Instantiating a console appender
        //
        SharedAppenderPtr _ConsoleAppender(new ConsoleAppender());
        _ConsoleAppender->setName(LOG4CPLUS_TEXT("AppenderName"));

        //
        // Creating a pattern to display log events
        //
        log4cplus::tstring pattern = LOG4CPLUS_TEXT("%L %F %r %d{%m/%d/%y %H:%M:%S}  %-5p %c - %m%n");

        //
        // Instantiating a layout object with PatternLayout
        //
        _Layout = std::auto_ptr<Layout>(new log4cplus::PatternLayout(pattern));

        //
        // Attaching the layout object to the appender object
        //
        _ConsoleAppender->setLayout(_Layout);

        //
        // Getting root logger and adding the Console Appender with root
        // logger
        //
        Logger::getRoot().addAppender(_ConsoleAppender);
        Logger::getRoot().setAdditivity(FALSE);

        //
        // Instantiating a logger
        //
        Logger _Logger = Logger::getInstance(LOG4CPLUS_TEXT("_Logger"));
        _Logger.addAppender(_ConsoleAppender);
        _Logger.setAdditivity(FALSE);

        //
        // Printing the log messages on the console
        //
        switch( dwLogLevel )
        {
        case DEBUG_LEVEL:
            {
                _Logger.log(DEBUG_LOG_LEVEL, lpszLogMessage, lpszFileName, dwLineNumber);
                break;
            } // DEBUG_LEVEL
        case INFO_LEVEL:
            {
                _Logger.log(INFO_LOG_LEVEL, lpszLogMessage, lpszFileName, dwLineNumber);
                break;
            } // INFO_LEVEL
        case WARN_LEVEL:
            {
                _Logger.log(WARN_LOG_LEVEL, lpszLogMessage, lpszFileName, dwLineNumber);
                break;
            } // WARN_LEVEL
        case ERROR_LEVEL:
            {
                _Logger.log(ERROR_LOG_LEVEL, lpszLogMessage, lpszFileName, dwLineNumber);
                break;
            } // ERROR_LEVEL
        case FATAL_LEVEL:
            {
                _Logger.log(FATAL_LOG_LEVEL, lpszLogMessage, lpszFileName, dwLineNumber);
                break;
            } // 
        default:
            {
                HRESULT_FROM_WIN32(ERROR_INVALID_DATA);
                break;
            } // default
        } // switch

return hResult;
}
```

Now from my application i want to pass function name also.

eg.
application.cpp

```
int main()
    {
    LogMessage(DEBUG_LEVEL, __FILE__, __LINE__, __FUNCTION__, "This is main function");
    return 0;
    }
```

How should i print this log message to the console screen? This below function only takes file and line number as an argument. And i want to print  function name as well.

```
void log(LogLevel ll, const log4cplus::tstring& message,
                 const char* file=NULL, int line=-1) const;
```

**UPDATE:**
Sorry i forgot to mention i have #define my LogMessage function with PrintLogMessage

```
#define  PrintLogMessage(dwLogLevel, lpszLogMessage) \
                                LogMessage(dwLogLevel, _FILE, __LINE__, lpszLogMessage)
```

So in application i am using i need to write only this line

application.cpp

```
int main()
{
    PrintLogMessage(DEBUG_LEVEL, "This is main function");
return 0;
}
```

And i want to write similar kind of

```
 #define  PrintLogMessage(dwLogLevel, lpszLogMessage) \
                                    LogMessage(dwLogLevel, _FILE, __LINE__, __FUNCTION__, lpszLogMessage)
```

for `__FUNCTION__` functionality. I dont want user to write **FILE**, **LINE**, **FUNCTION** everytime.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this function from the `Logger` class instead:

```
void log (spi::InternalLoggingEvent const &) const;
```

Prepare the `InternalLoggingEvent` instance in advance. Use `InternalLoggingEvent::setFunction()` to set the function information on the event instance.

## UPDATE

I have re-read your question and the code I think your are not using log4cplus the way it is intended.

First off, your `LogMessage` should not be creating appenders or attaching appenders to loggers each time it is invoked. Appenders and loggers should be set up at the start of your application.

Take a look `loggingmacros.h` and the macros there. You can avoid having to define your own macros or functions if you use the `LOG4CPLUS_ERROR`, `LOG4CPLUS_INFO`, etc. macros. See the `tests/` directory for some examples of how to use these macros.

If you want to still avoid using the log4cplus provided macros, take a look at the source in `loggingmacros.cxx`:

```
void
macro_forced_log (log4cplus::Logger const & logger,
    log4cplus::LogLevel log_level, log4cplus::tstring const & msg,
    char const * filename, int line, char const * func)
{
    log4cplus::spi::InternalLoggingEvent & ev = internal::get_ptd ()->forced_log_ev;
    ev.setLoggingEvent (logger.getName (), log_level, msg, filename, line);
    ev.setFunction (func ? func : "");
    logger.forcedLog (ev);
}
```

This function is internally used by the various `LOG4CPLUS_*()` macros in `loggingmacros.h`. It shows you how to fill the `InternalLoggingEvent` instance and how to force its log. Use it as an example for your own `LogMessage()` function.

You would have to replace `forcedLog()` with `log()` to have it check the Logger threshold.

One implementation could look like this:

```
HRESULT
LogMessage(
    __in    DWORD dwLogLevel,
    __in    LPCSTR lpszFileName,
    __in    DWORD dwLineNumber,
    __in    LPCSTR lpszLogMessage,
    __in    LPCSTR lpszFunction)
{
    log4cplus::spi::InternalLoggingEvent ev;
    log4cplus::Logger logger (Logger::getRoot());
    ev.setLoggingEvent (logger.getName (), dwLogLevel, lpszLogMessage, lpszFileName,
        dwLineNumber);
    ev.setFunction (func ? lpszFunction : "");
    logger.forcedLog (ev); // or logger.log(ev)

    return S_OK;
}

#define PrintLogMessage(ll, msg) \
    LogMessage(ll, __FILE__, __LINE__, msg, LOG4CPLUS_MACRO_FUNCTION())
```

Comment: Thanks wilx for replying.
I have added This code after instantiating the _Logger.
`spi::InternalLoggingEvent *ent = new InternalLoggingEvent();
        ent->setLoggingEvent(LOG4CPLUS_TEXT("_Logger"), dwLogLevel, lpszLogMessage, lpszFileName, dwLineNumber);
        ent->setFunction(lpszFunctionName);`

Comment: And in switch case statement i am using `mqLogger.log(*ent);`. But it is not printing on console screen at all. Can you please tell me where i am doing wrong. I am getting all the values in ent object of spi::InternalLoggingEvent class.

Comment: I think i am not creating `InternalLoggingEvent` instance in a right way.

Comment: Ty Wilx. `logger.forcedlog()` worked. I know i am creating an instance of appender again and again during `LogMessage()` function call. But in end I am using `log4cplus::Logger::shutdown();`. Will it not destroy the instances which i have created in my function?

Comment: @Ankit: It will destroy the appender and the logger but it is not the way you should do it.

Answer (score 0):

If you can't modify the **LogMessage** function you could use this method:

```
int main()
{
   LogMessage(DEBUG_LEVEL, __FILE__, __LINE__, "This is "__FUNCTION__" function");
   // notice the missing commas ------------------------^------------^
}
```

Since there is no comma the compiler will concatenate the output of **__FUNCTION__** and your message.

**EDIT:**

```
#define  PrintLogMessage(dwLogLevel, lpszLogMessage) \
LogMessage(dwLogLevel, _FILE, __LINE__, __FUNCTION__ lpszLogMessage)
```

or

```
#define  PrintLogMessage(dwLogLevel, lpszLogMessage) \
LogMessage(dwLogLevel, _FILE, __LINE__, lpszLogMessage __FUNCTION__)
```

or

```
#define  PrintLogMessage(dwLogLevel, lpszLogMessage) \
LogMessage(dwLogLevel, _FILE, __LINE__, lpszLogMessage __FUNCTION__ "function")
```

or

```
#define  PrintLogMessage(dwLogLevel, lpszLogMessage) \
LogMessage(dwLogLevel, _FILE, __LINE__, std::string(lpszLogMessage) + std::string(__FUNCTION__))
```

Comment: While writing PrintLogMessage(dwLogLevel, lpszLogMessage); 

it is saying `error : #define  PrintLogMessage(dwLogLevel, lpszLogMessage) \
LogMessage(dwLogLevel, _FILE, __LINE__, __FUNCTION__ lpszLogMessage) expected ')'`

Comment: lpszLogMessage must be a string literal, try the new method

Comment: Yes. lpszLogMessage is a log message string. But these methods are not working.